# How to change main hosted domain?

Tags: wordpress, dns, hosting, cpanel

I'm new at this and today I wanted to change my hosting's main domain from blog.mywebsite.com (was running ok) to mywebsite.com. Before entering CPanel I have a page on my hosting that gives me the option to change the domain so I did it.

The problem is now I'm getting a page that says: The website is not properly configured on this server
If you are the owner of this website, please contact your hosting provider

I believe that forcing a domain change like that isn't the correct way to do it so here I am looking for some help :)

ps: I have my Wordpress completely backed up with plugin Duplicator from blog.mywebsite.com so I'm up to erase everything. Also on my DNS Manager I can see blog.mywebsite.com and mywebsite.com pointing to the same IP.

**UPDATE**
I deleted the blog.mywebsite.com from the DNS Manager and now it loads mybesite.com but without any image/CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in wp-config.php

```
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'mywebsite.com' );
define( 'WP_HOME', 'mywebsite.com' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally at first you need to change your Wordpress location using wordpress control panel and move the files to public_html directory .

Now in this case define the wordpress directory location in wp-config.php file

```
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'mywebsite.com' );
define( 'WP_HOME', 'mywebsite.com' );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can update your WordPress site URL by adding code in wp-config.php or removing URL completely from the database using search and find plugin.

Or you  can use MySQL script to  change URL

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'http://www.oldurl.com', 'http://www.newurl.com') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';

UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'http://www.oldurl.com','http://www.newurl.com');

UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'http://www.oldurl.com', 'http://www.newurl.com');

UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value,'http://www.oldurl.com','http://www.newurl.com');
```

You can also refer to this Article [How to Change Website URL Without Accessing the wp-admin Panel](https://hostadvice.com/how-to/how-to-change-website-url-without-accessing-the-wp-admin-panel/)

[How to Configure a WordPress Website After its Migration](https://hostadvice.com/how-to/how-to-configure-a-wordpress-website-after-its-migration/)